# Why is the function $f(x)=5^x+5^{|x|}$ not one-one?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

One-one function: $f$ is said to be **one-one** (or injective), if $\forall a_1, a_2 ∈ A$, $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$ then $a_1=a_2$.

Why is the above function not one-one if for every value in the domain there is a unique image?

Comment: Every element of the *image*, must have a unique preimage. Did you try plotting this?

Comment: The definition does not say, "For every value in the domain there is a unique image."  Rather, it says, "For every element in the image, there is a unique pre-image."

Comment: You already know it's a function (for every value in the domain, there is a unique image).  The condition "one-to-one" means more than just that: for every value in the image, there is a unique value in the domain that maps to it.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+5%5Ex%2B5%5E%7Cx%7C

Comment: got it thank you

Comment: You know that $f(0)=2$ and the limits that go to positive and negative infinity, respectively, both go to infinity so the intermediate value theorem ought to give you two values on either side of zero that are equal.

Comment: $f(-1)=5\frac15=f(\log_5\frac{5\frac15}2)$